# How do you define a tetrad if your metric is non-diagonal?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

I have a spacetime metric with $g_{11}:=0$ and $g_{01}=g_{10}=f(r,t,\phi)$, the other two non-zero components being diagonal. I am not sure how to find a tetrad basis.

Comment: Can you write the full metric please?

Answer (score 2):

In general given a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, an orthonormal basis $e^a$ is such that,
$$\mathrm ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm dx^\mu \mathrm dx^\nu = e^a e^b \eta_{ab}$$

where $\eta = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,\dots,-1)$. So, if you write out the left-hand side, and the right-hand side, you get an equation you have to solve. More explicitly,

$$g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{dx}^\mu \mathrm{d}x^\nu = (e^0)^2 - (e^1)^2 - \dots - (e^i)^2$$

for $\mu,\nu = 0, \dots,i$. In case you need the vielbein to convert between indices, recall that $e^a_\mu \mathrm{dx}^\mu = e^a$ by definition and that $e^\mu_a$ is the matrix inverse of $e^a_\mu$.

Comment: Does this mean that there could be several components of the basis vectors that could be chosen to be zero?

Comment: Yes, because there is a lot of freedom in choosing an orthonormal frame (=basis) for a given metric. Any rigid rotation of the frame corresponds to the same metric.